# SwiftUI - No exact matches in call to initializer, passing array using state/binding var between views

Tags: xcode, swiftui, binding, state

I am struggling trying to figure out how to access an array of ExerciseSets in one view after creating this array in a different view. ExSetView hosts SetRowView, SetRowView hosts SetRowView2 and I want to use the input from SetRowView2 to inform a button in ExSetView

I have setsInWorkout in ExSetView as a binding var and keep getting the following error: "No exact matches in call to initializer - Found candidate with type '(Binding<*>) -> Binding<Optional<*>>'"

1st View ExSetView: Button to save setsInWorkout to workout, leads to SetRowView
2nd View SetRowView: leads to SetRowView2
3rd View SetRowView2: create an empty array called setsInWorkout, save ExerciseSets to this array

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
struct ExSetView: View { 
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var viewContext
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    let date = Date()
    @State var selectedItems = Set<Exercise>()
    @State private var sets : Int = 1
    @Binding var setsInWorkout = [ExerciseSet]

    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            VStack (alignment: .leading) {
               Text("Sets in workout: \($setsInWorkout.count)")
                HStack {
                    Text(date, style: .date)                
                    Button("Done"){
                        // save workout using setsInWorkout
                    }      
                }

                ForEach(Array(selectedItems), id: \.self) { e in
                    HStack{
                        Text(e.exercisename)
                    }
                    ForEach(0..<sets, id: \.self) { number in
                        SetRowView(selectedItem: e)
                    }
                }
            }
        }      
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

extension View {
    func hideKeyboard() {
        UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
    }
}

struct SetRowView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var viewContext
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @State var selectedItem = Exercise()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            Button(action: {
                self.sets += 1
            }) {
                Text("Add Set")
            }
            
            ForEach(0..<sets, id: \.self) { number in
               SetRowView2(selectedItem: selectedItem)
             
            }
        }}
  
}
```

```
struct SetRowView2: View {
    @State private var weight = ""
    @State private var reps = ""
    @State private var sets : Int = 1
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var viewContext
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @State var selectedItem = Exercise()
    @State var setsInWorkout = [ExerciseSet]()
    
    func addExerciseSet() {
        let newExerciseSet = ExerciseSet(context: viewContext)
        newExerciseSet.exercise = selectedItem
        newExerciseSet.dateCompleted = Date()
        newExerciseSet.id = UUID()
        newExerciseSet.reps = Int16(reps) ?? 1
        newExerciseSet.weight = Int16(weight) ?? 1
        
        setsInWorkout.append(newExerciseSet)
        try? viewContext.save()
        dismiss()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack{
            ForEach(0..<sets, id: \.self) { number in
                Form {
                    Section {
                        TextField("Reps", text: $reps)
                            .frame(width:20)
                            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                self.hideKeyboard()
                            }
                        TextField("Weight", text: $weight)
                            .frame(width:20)
                            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                self.hideKeyboard()                         
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            Button(action: {
                addExerciseSet()
            }) {
                Text("Done")              
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: `@Binding var setsInWorkout = [ExerciseSet]` Bindings shouldn't be declared with a value -- they should always be passed in. Maybe you meant `@Binding var setsInWorkout: [ExerciseSet]`

Comment: Thank you both, this resolved that error. But now, on the view that contains the NavigationLink to ExSetView, I get an error "Missing argument for parameter 'setsInWorkout' in call" even though that view is unrelated to setsInWorkout, it simply calls ExSetView.